# Youtube Data API v3 quota usage application level

Tags: google-api, youtube, youtube-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

I want to create an app for uploading videos to youtube. So I used youtube data API. And I will serve a service for my users to uploading video youtube.

And Official documents says that:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started?hl=tr#calculating-quota-usage

> Google calculates your quota usage by assigning a cost to each
> request. Different types of operations have different quota costs. For
> example:
>
> A read operation that retrieves a list of resources -- channels,
> videos, playlists -- usually costs 1 unit. A write operation that
> creates, updates, or deletes a resource usually has costs 50 units. A
> search request costs 100 units. A video upload costs 1600 units. The
> Quota costs for API requests table shows the quota cost of each API
> method. With these rules in mind, you can estimate the number of
> requests that your application could send per day without exceeding
> your quota.

Is this quotas for a application level or user level. If it is for application level, In this way I have 6 video upload credit from youtube?

What is the clear explanation for this case? Is there any difference about app level quota between user level quota?

Answer (score 1):

The quota is accounted *per Google project*. That is that each Google project has allocated an amount of daily quota (by default 10000 units) and each API call (being it through an API key or through an access token obtained upon completing successfully an OAuth 2.0 authentication/authorization flow) is deducted out of that quota amount.

Thus, by means of a given Google project, one given application -- if granted permission by several users to access their YouTube channel upon the successful completions of OAuth 2.0 authentication/authorization flows -- could well upload videos to multiple channels.

But, as you noted, in case of one having allocated an amount of 10000 units of quota to his/her Google project, the number of videos that may be uploaded on any given day cannot exceed six (if not counting the other API calls the application may issue).

Of course there's the possibility to apply for quota extensions (by filling in [this form](https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form?hl=en)); but be aware of the fact that, according to the experience of the users of this forum, the answer from Google does not arrive shortly.

Answer (score 1):

These are application level quotas.  When your application runs and you authorize a user the user uploads a video to their account.

If we look at the quota for my system

[image]

My application itself has a quota limit of 10000.  but each user can max use 180,000 quota.  Which is useless as my application itself can only do 10000.
My application itself can use 1,800,000 per minute but again its useless as the total for the application is 10,000.

[Intro to YouTube API and cost based quota for beginners 2021.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MHUGuw1Agnc)